# Regex to match the first word + optional values inside ( ) after an identifier?

Tags: .net, regex, string

I am a little lost figuring out a proper (.Net) regex to match / extract information out of strings following these criteria:

- The input string *may* have optional, leading whitespaces
- The Regex shall only match, if a specific keyword is either at the very beginning of the input string  or right after the aforementioned whitespaces.
- This keyword may be followed by either a ':' and/or one or more whitespaces
- However, the first value/match to extract should be the first word after the identifier and only if it's an alphanumeric one ('-' and '_' characters are allowed)
- Now comes the tricky part: *optionally*, there *may* be one or more values (whitespace separated) inside parentheses immediately following up the match above that should be matched one by one in a separate group, if the (..) values are available.

So basically the following might occur:

```
Sample #1:
----------
Identifier key_abc_1
----------
>> this should match 'key_abc_1'

Sample #2:
----------
    Identifier: key_abc_1 some other text after the key
----------
>> this should match 'key_abc_1'


Sample #3:
----------
Identifier: key_abc_1(AB CD EF) some other text after key with paranthesis
----------
>> this should match 'key_abc_1' and as a second group containing 'AB', 'CD' and 'EF'


Sample #4:
----------
    Identifier: key_abc_1 some other text after key with paranthesis (AB CD EF) some other text after key with paranthesis
----------
>> this should match 'key_abc_1' only

Sample #5:
----------
    Identifier: key_abc_1 (AB CD EF) some other text after
----------
>> this should also only match 'key_abc_1' only

Sample #6:
----------
key_abc_1(AB CD EF) some other text after but no identifier at the beginning
----------
>> this should not match at all!
```

Lookbehind got me so far to match the key_abc_1 but translating the optional ()-values and other constraints into a proper regex is bending my mind a bit. Maybe someone has an idea how to do this properly / reliably and can give me a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as a second group containing 'AB', 'CD' and 'EF'

use this pattern

```
^\s*Identifier:?\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:\(([^)(]*)\))?
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/67)

> should be matched one by one in a separate group

use this pattern

```
^\s*Identifier:?\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:\(([^)( ]+)[ )])?|\G(?!^)([^ \r\n)]+)[ )]
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/68)